# how to get a sql rank query working to find the rank of a specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I try to do a rank query but i fail to get it working correctly. The rank is calculated by the highest market_cap followed by the highest id in case the market_cap has the same value, the condition active must be 1. I only want the rank of a specific id in the end.

Table:

| id | market_cap | active | expected rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 67000 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 197000 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 67000 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 127000 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 17000 | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | 37000 | 1 | 5 |
| 7 | 2237000 | 0 | / |

This is the PHP(Laravel) code that does exactly that and is working, but i want to use it as plain SQL for speed improvements since my table has 20k rows.

```
    $token_list = DB::table('tokens')->where('active', 1)->orderBy('market_cap', 'desc')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get(array('id'));
    foreach($token_list as $key => $token){
        if($token->id == $data['token']->id){
            $token_rank = $key+1;
        }
    }
```

Current Query that is not working yet (it stops to work for all results that have a market_cap of 0, which are thousands, they all get the same ranking which is the last rank number):

```
    $rank_query = DB::select("SELECT FIND_IN_SET(market_cap, ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(market_cap ORDER BY market_cap DESC, id DESC) FROM tokens WHERE active = 1)) AS rank FROM tokens WHERE id = {$data['token']->id}");
    $token_rank = $rank_query[0]->rank;
```

Comment: You don't do the same in Laravel and SQL. So whatever you're doing, it's not comparable.

Comment: @shaedrich Thats the thing. I want to get the same result in SQL as in my PHP. The result is almost identical already, just the market_cap 0 results rank all the same. Everything that has a market_cap ranks the same as my php code.

Comment: Maybe there is a misunderstanding: Your raw query is imitating the Laravel query but is not equivalent. What you're doing in your raw sql can still be splitted up into query builder statements. So your question doesn't seem reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

In a SQL query, you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (case when active
                   then row_number() over (partition by active order by market_cap desc, id desc)
              end) as ranking
      from t
     ) t
where . . .
```

You would put your filtering conditions in the outer query.

Comment: This is it! I tried this kind of syntax before, but i must have done something wrong. This works, thanks a lot, will read into the exact meaning of that query since it still looks a little confusing to me.

Comment: It seems like MySQL doesn't support "analytic functions" like ROW_NUMBER() OVER, RANK(), etc. for mysql 5.7(which is use on my live server). The support starts with mysql 8.
Is there any other way for mysql 5.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this with Laravel's query builder as well. There's no need to use raw sql.

```
$marketCapQuery = DB::table('tokens')->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(market_cap ORDER BY market_cap DESC, id DESC)'->where('active', 1)->toSql();
$rank_query = DB::table('tokens')->selectRaw("FIND_IN_SET(market_cap, ( '.$marketCapQuery.') AS rank'->where('id', $data['token']->id);
$token_rank = $rank_query[0]->rank;
```